# Cassandra development

Tags: cassandra

I've been playing with Cassandra and I have been thinking of contributing to the development of Cassandra (inspired by the connector projects) but I'm at loss of where to start... The documentation is not clear on the interfaces, etc, for an aspiring developer.

If I'm not wrong, almost all the codes for Cassandra has been written in Java. For example, I'm thinking of starting by writing my own C++ driver and once comfortable, I would start on addressing issues/enchancement...

Any guidance, please?

Comment: For an existing example of a C/C++ driver for Cassandra, see DataStax' [cpp-driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

@ABCD - There are drivers in Python and Java. If you are looking to write one using C++ as mentioned by @Castaglia you can find a starting point. If you are trying to contribute to Cassandra, there are some executables like sstableloader which could benefit from being written in other languages.

Cassandra's cassandra-stress is one more such tool that is used and this can use your work into C++ (translation, enhancements, etc). This way you are making Cassandra and some peripheral components accessible in other languages (so you'd be helping people have more standalone tools that they could use without having to deploy complete clusters and have prereqs like Java version etc) 
Also, in that effort you'd definitely need to read up and research, so you are already enhancing your knowledge.

Also, towards your goal - https://academy.datastax.com/ - you can learn more through the videos. I hope this helps!